# Interpret Assembly Code

Tags: c, function, assembly, x86-64, x86

I found the following assembly code and I have no idea what it is supposed to be doing (mainly because cmovg follows the movl instruction ):

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 8(%ebp), %edx
movl %edx, %eax
sarl $31, %eax
testl %edx, %edx
movl $1, %edx
cmovg %edx, %eax
popl %ebp
ret
```

So here is how I have interpreted it so far:
pushes onto stack

a new pointer (stack pointer) creates to point at the same location as base pointer

gets the input (let's call it x)

copies x into register %eax (res = x)

res = res >> 31 sign extension

tests x

sets x = 1

if >, res = x

restores pointer

returns res

However, I am not sure what the significance of this subroutine is. To me it seems useless. I would appreciate it if you could point out what is being done here.

Comment: Where did you find it? Should give you a clue what the purpose is.

Comment: In a document along with tons of other subroutines that are meant to carry out mathematical functions. The document is not annotated so it is very useless in that sense.

Comment: I am guessing it is some sort of a mathematical operation. But that does not help me much.

Comment: Did you lose your source code and want to reconstruct it based on your executable code?

Comment: There is no source code. I started out with the machine code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code returns the sign of X. In C:

```
int sign(int x) {
    if (x>0)
        return 1;
    else if (x==0)
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

The instruction `sarl $31, %eax` will put `-1` in `eax` if it was negative, or `0` otherwise. Then the `cmovg` instruction will replace this value with `1` if `x` was positive.

Comment: wouldn't you still get 0 if x = 1?!

Comment: @DanP.: No. The `test %edx, %edx` instruction compares `x` with `0`. Since it's greater than 0 the `cmovg` instruction will put 1 in `eax`.